# Simple SSL socket in C++, Windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, ssl

I have two C++ projects, which **communicate via a socket** using `winsock2`. Now, I want to encrypt the communication using SSL (this is the easiest and fastest way, right?).

I tried to find any library or good tutorial, but I did not find a good one that worked for me (e.g. [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24379/SSL-Convert-your-Plain-Sockets-to-SSL-Sockets-in-a?msg=5243602) sounds simple, but I wasn't able to include the header file without errors).

Do you have any suggestion / good tutorial /good library for **encrypting winsock2-sockets *fast***?

Comment: http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SecureServerSocket.html

Comment: Are you wanting to stick with the schannel api or are you willing to switch to a different api? If you want to stick with schannel, it would probably be better to troubleshoot the errors you are having instead of pointing you to different samples.

Comment: @jveazey Which other api do you recommend?

Comment: _'Do you have any suggestion / good tutorial /good library ...'_ - this is __asking for a close vote__. Here is the close reason: 'Questions asking us to recommend or find __a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource__ are off-topic for Stack Overflow ...'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with a low level language like C++, SSL/TLS is not simple. You have to deal with learning one of the [many SSL/TLS libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Libraries). Additionally, while some of the samples for these libraries may seem simple, the nuances of SSL/TLS are not.

I *can* point you to several libraries that work on Windows, as well as their tags in Stackoverflow.

- [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html) ([tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost+ssl))
- [GnuTLS](http://www.gnutls.org/) ([tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnutls))
- [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) ([tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl))
- [Schannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374782(v=vs.85).aspx) ([tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schannel))
- [libressl](http://www.libressl.org) ([tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libressl))